# Unable to open port in GoogleCloud VM

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I hosted a Flask API in google cloud VM having 16.04 LTS Ubuntu OS through the port 5000. VM has both private IP and public IP assigned to it and have created a firewall rule for opening the 5000 port. I am able to access the API by logging in to the VM. But when I tried to access it using public IP I was not able to do it and I get the following error:-
Failed to connect to 35.200.001.01 port 5000: No route to host
What should I do to expose APIs publicly?
Have provided the screenshot of firewall configuration for your reference.

[image]

Comment: I've tried to ping your machine but I didn't have success, have you turned it off? or changed the IP? if you could do the telnet command to your instance successfully, this means that the Flask application is failing somehow, as the ports configuration seems to be ok

Answer (score 0):

add `tcp:5000` instead of `all` protocols and ports (which would take down the firewall)... in case it still not works, once check inside the instance, if the port on the external interface can be accessed. Flask binds per default to IP `127.0.0.1:5000` - while it should be `0.0.0.0:5000`, so that one could access it from the localhost, internal and external interfaces.